# How to make object with parent child thing?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a class `Tile`, and a class `Terrain` which extends the `Tile` class.

In the `Terrain` class I have other classes, such as `Dirt` and `Rock`, both extends the `Terrain` class.

I want to make (for example) a `Dirt` object in the `Tile` class

The Tile class:

```
public class Tile {

      int id;

      public static Tile dirt1 = new Dirt(1);

      public Tile(int id) {
            this.id = id;
      }
}
```

The Terrain class:

```
public class Terrain extends Tile {

      public Terrain(int id) {
            super(id);
      }

      public class Dirt extends Terrain{
            public Dirt(int id) {
                  super(id);
            }
      }

      public class Rock extends Terrain{
            public Rock(int id) {
                  super(id);
            }
      }


}
```

How should I construct a `Dirt`, or `Rock` object?

Comment: This is not syntactically valid Java code

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Doesn't the part `class dirt(id)` give you a compile-time error?

Comment: No sorry. I made a mistake here. I tried to write the code from memory. Edited!

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. I'm really not used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eater make the `Dirt` and `Rock` classes static, and instantiate them :

```
public static Tile dirt1 = new Terrain.Dirt(1);
```

Or if you what them non-static you need an create an instance of `Terrain` before creating instance of `Dirt`

```
public static Tile dirt1 = new Terrain().Dirt(1);
```

in this case you need to define a no arg constructor in `Terrain` and `Tile`